# Priority of keymapping commands

Tags: key-bindings, cua-mode

In another question ([IDO rebind C-j to C-<RET>](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37235/ido-rebind-c-j-to-c-ret)), Seraph asked about defining the `<C-return>` key for ido-mode.

It turned out that the key was already bound in `cua-global-keymap`, which overrode its binding in `ido-common-completion-map`.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `emacs -Q`
2. `M-x cua-mode RET`
3. `M-x ido-mode RET`
4. ```el
   (define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "<C-return>")
     (lambda () 
       (interactive)
       (message "C-j called")))
   ```
5. `C-x C-e`
6. `M-x ido-dired RET`
7. `C-h k C-return`

Which turns out to be bound to `cua-set-rectangle-mark` in `cua-global-keymap`, as opposed to the anonymous command above in `ido-completion-map`.

As a workaround, I recommended removing the definition in `cua-global-map`.

Question: is there a way to make the definition in `ido-common-completion-map` override the definition in `cua-global-map`?

Comment: See (elisp) [Active Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It turned out that the key was already bound in `cua-global-keymap`, which overrode its binding in `ido-common-completion-map`.

Indeed, this is because `cua-mode` uses `emulation-mode-map-alists`, which has one of the highest priorities in key lookup, to store and select from many of its key bindings. See [`(elisp) Active Keymaps`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html), [`(elisp) Searching Keymaps`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-Keymaps.html) and [`(elisp) Controlling Active Maps`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Controlling-Active-Maps.html) for more information on this.

> is there a way to make the definition in `ido-common-completion-map` override the definition in `cua-global-map`?

There are, of course, several ways to achieve this, but I'm not sure which one would prove the simplest or most desirable, elegant or robust. Here are a couple of suggestions:

1. Simply unbind the key from `cua-global-keymap` if it is unwanted:

   ```el
   (with-eval-after-load 'cua-base
     (define-key cua-global-keymap [C-return] nil))
   ```
2. Try to override the `cua-mode` overrides in `emulation-mode-map-alists`:

   ```el
   (defun my-shave-yak ()
     "No-one was using those CPU cycles anyway."
     (interactive)
     (message ">>> Hello, World!"))

   (defvar my-ido-map
     (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
       (define-key map [C-return] #'my-shave-yak)
       map)
     "Keymap for personal `ido' bindings.")

   ;; Bind keys as we want them ideally,
   ;; assuming no pesky external overrides are in place
   (with-eval-after-load 'ido
     ;; Perhaps composing keymaps or similar
     ;; would avoid duplicating `my-ido-map'
     (define-key ido-common-completion-map [C-return] #'my-shave-yak))

   ;; Activate `my-ido-map' with `cua-mode' and place
   ;; it at a lower index than `cua--keymap-alist'
   (add-to-ordered-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists
                        `((cua-mode . ,my-ido-map))
                        0)
   ```