# unbind ALL C-x and C-c shortcuts in org-mode with CUA-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, cua-mode

For a special purpose application of emacs with org-mode I want to dramatically simplify the shortcuts. I'm already quite satisfied with my config based on CUA mode.

The one thing that bothers me still is that I C-c and C-x initiates the original sequences when no selection is active. How can I disable this?

Comment: does this question help?
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37277/priority-of-keymapping-commands

Comment: You can fine-tune the behavior of those key-sequences with [ergoemacs](https://ergoemacs.github.io/).