# Make ido-completing-map override minibuffer-inactive-mode-map

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer, ido

I'm trying to bind a key in `ido-completing-map`, and I want it to override the key-binding with the same key from `minibuffer-inactive-mode-map`. But the latter seems to take precedence. How can I remedy this ?

Comment: maybe unbind the key in the minibuffer...mode-map. `(define-key minibuffer-inactive-mode-map (kbd "THE-KEY") nil)`

Comment: @jue Well, I would like to keep that binding for minibuffer situations other than ido...

Comment: read here to give a keymap precedence over another keymap: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37277/priority-of-keymapping-commands  maybe this solves it for you.