# How to change M-v to use cut-paste?

Tags: key-bindings

I am switching from Aquamacs to Emacs on OSX v28.2 and trying to setup my preferred key bindings. I set

```
'(ns-alternate-modifier 'alt)
'(ns-command-modifier 'meta)
'(ns-control-modifier 'control)
'(ns-function-modifier 'none)
'(ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)
'(ns-right-command-modifier 'hyper)
'(ns-right-control-modifier 'super)
```

Then tried setting

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-v") 'cua-paste)
```

But no matter what I try M-v (cmd-v on Mac) always shows the following when enter F1-k M-v

```
M-v runs the command delete-selection-repeat-replace-region (found in
cua--cua-keys-keymap), which is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp
function in ‘delsel.el’.

It is bound to M-v.
```

My other bindings are working fine, just not M-v

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'clipboard-kill-region)
  (global-set-key "\M-c" 'cua-copy-region)
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-v") 'cua-paste)
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-z") 'undo)
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-s") 'save-buffer)
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-w") 'kill-buffer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message indicates that a command in `cua--cua-keys-keymap` overrides your binding for `M-v`. This overriding binding is created when `cua-mode` is enabled. `cua-mode` puts its keymaps in `emulation-mode-map-alists` which gives them very high priority, see [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37283/33424) or [this Emacs manual section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-Keymaps.html).

One way to make your binding come through is to disable the `M-v` binding set by cua-mode (or change it to something else) by putting the following in your init.el:

```
(add-hook 'cua-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key cua--cua-keys-keymap (kbd "M-v") nil)))
```

Comment: Sweetness prevails! Thanks!